# Regular Expression: Zip Code only 9 or 10 Digits with Dash

Tags: java, regex

We are allowing US Zip Codes as only (1) 9 digits, or (2) 10 digits with a dash before the last 4 digits.

The following regexp gives a compilation error:

```
private static final String USZIPCODE_MATCH_FORMAT_REGEXP = "^\d{5}[\\-]?\d{4}$";

Invalid escape sequence
```

Comment: `\\d` ...........................

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java you need to escape the `\` as well. So, you need

```
"^\\d{5}[\\-]?\\d{4}$"
```

Also, you can specify the hyphen simply as

```
"^\\d{5}-?\\d{4}$"
```

The `-` is not special when used outside `[]`.